# How would I setParent and set permissions in a channel? Discord Bot Coding

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

How would I setParent as well as have permissions set for when a channel is created with my command "^new"
So, as of right now, I have this code:

```
exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    
    if (msg.author.bot) return;

    const reason = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    const SupportRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Staff");

    if(!SupportRole) {
        msg.channel.send("Please create a role called 'Staff' before using this command!");
    }

    if(!reason) {
        return msg.channel.send("Please specify a reason!")
    }

    const ticketChannel = await msg.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${msg.author.username}`).then(c => {
        const sr = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Staff")
        const everyone = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone")
        c.updateOverwrite(sr, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });
        c.updateOverwrite(everyone, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        });
        c.updateOverwrite(msg.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });
        let CreatedTicketEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("New Ticket")
            .setDescription(`<@${msg.author.id}> Your support ticket is <#${c.id}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
        msg.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed)
        
        let GreetEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("New Ticket!")
            .addField(`${msg.author.username}'s Support Ticket`,"The staff team will be right with you!")
            .addField("Reason:", reason)
            .addField("Type ^close to close the ticket.", "Staff Team")
            .setTimestamp()
        c.send(GreetEmbed)
        msg.delete()
    }).then((channel) => {
        const categoryId = '774032663560192000';
        ticketChannel.setParent(categoryId);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    
    var channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "ticket-logs")
    
    if(!channel) return msg.channel.send("There is no channel called 'ticket-logs'");
    
    
    let LogEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("New Support Ticket")
        .addField(`${msg.author.username}'s Support Ticket`,"React with ✅ when dealing with / have dealt with ticket.")
        .addField("Reason:", reason)
        .setTimestamp()
    channel.send(LogEmbed).then(messageReaction => {
        messageReaction.react('✅')
    })
}
```

So, when I have both the setParent and the updateOverwrite codes, it either doesn't move them under the category, or doesn't set the permissions and they don't send the embeds I have created either. How would I fix this?

Comment: Instead of creating a callback, you can do all of this *inside* the `channels.create()` function. Check the [second parameter](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)

Comment: Please elaborate?

Comment: The second parameter of [`GuildChannelManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) is an object that accepts the `parent` and `overwrites` properties, so you can set all of that within the initial function instead of using a `then()` function.

Comment: How would I set the parent with that function, I changed it to;

`const sr = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Staff")
const everyone = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone")

msg.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${msg.author.username}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [
     {
       id: msg.author.id,
       allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
    },
    {
       id: sr.id,
       allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],

    },
  ],
})`